# How to parse XML in VBA and retrieve specific values

Tags: excel, vba

I've already spent two weeks searching unsuccessfully how to parse one specific XML and fetch just few values. I already tried every single code on internet until I found one that solved part of my problem.

The XML i'm trying to fetch it's from U.S Department of Agriculture, and is free to access.

https://apps.fas.usda.gov/psdonline/app/index.html#/app/about

```
    Dim xmlDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Dim xmlNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
    Dim xmlNodeList As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList
    Dim myNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode

    Dim URL As String, APIkey As String

    APIkey = "8DB688F8-1E22-4031-B581-59C221ECDDA6"

    URL = "https://apps.fas.usda.gov/PSDOnlineDataServices/api/CommodityData/GetCommodityDataByYear?commodityCode=2222000&marketYear=2018"

    Set xmlDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    xmlDoc.async = False

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    .Open "GET", URL, False
    .SetRequestHeader "Accept", "text/xml"
    .SetRequestHeader "API_KEY", APIkey
    .Send
    xmlDoc.loadXML .ResponseText
End With

Set xmlNodeList = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("*")
    For Each xmlNode In xmlNodeList
        For Each myNode In xmlNode.childNodes
          If myNode.nodeType = NODE_TEXT Then
            Debug.Print xmlNode.nodeName & "=" & xmlNode.text
          End If
        Next myNode
    Next xmlNode
    Set xmlDoc = Nothing
End Sub
```

The response of this code show the entire XML listed, but when I try to find one specific node, the code result it's nothing.

in

```
Set xmlNodeList = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("*")
```

I've tried to use the address "//AttributeDescription", but apparently just work using the "*".

I need to receive, for example, The response below:

AttributeDescription=Production

CountryName=Brazil

Value=0.00000

I did my best trying to get the right response and I also consider that the XML structure it's not in the right format due the lack of response when addressing...

Is there anything that I can do to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two separate issues here.

MSXML2 has issues using XPath when the XML document has a default namespace - see [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/313372/prb-msxml-4-0-matching-nodes-are-not-returned-when-you-run-xpath-queri) for details. At the start of the downloaded document from the USDA site, there are some namespace declarations:

```
<ArrayOfCommodityData xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/PSDOnline.DataServices.Models">
```

There are two namespaces declared here. One with the prefix `i` and a default namespace that covers any element which does not have a namespace prefix. If you look at a "CalendarYear" entry in the XML document - `<CalendarYear i:nil="true" />` - then you can see that "CalendarYear" is in the default namespace whereas "nil" is in the "i" namespace.

To make MSXML2 work with default namespaces, you have to declare a namespace which has the same URI as the default namespace. This is done using the SelectionNamespaces property of the XML document, like this:

```
xmlDoc.SetProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:r='http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/PSDOnline.DataServices.Models'"
```

I chose `r` as the namespace but the name you choose is irrelevant - it just has to be different from any other namespaces in the document.

This leads on to the second problem. You are using `getElementsByTagName` which just takes a tag name as a parameter but you are passing in an XPath string. To deal with an XPath string, you need to use `SelectNodes` instead and you need to use the namespace we added, like this:

```
Set xmlNodeList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//r:AttributeDescription")
```

Comment: the robust way. Doh me! +

Comment: thanks a lot, that worked like a charm, and your solution was perfect in every aspect (didactically and functional). Your answer made me learn a new thing and that's amazing. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Concise & comprehensible explanations +) @barrowc

Answer (score 3):

It's a namespace issue I think. There are people more familiar with this who can likely fix how to add properly and then reference. I did try adding the two namespaces with the usual syntax `.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", namespace` but still failed to set objects so guess I did something wrong.

An interim, less robust solution is as follows:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()
    Dim xmlDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Dim URL As String, APIkey As String

    APIkey = "key"

    URL = "https://apps.fas.usda.gov/PSDOnlineDataServices/api/CommodityData/GetCommodityDataByYear?commodityCode=2222000&marketYear=2018"

    Set xmlDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", URL, False
        .SetRequestHeader "Accept", "text/xml"
        .SetRequestHeader "API_KEY", APIkey
        .Send
        xmlDoc.LoadXML .responseText
    End With

    Dim node As IXMLDOMElement, r As Long
    For Each node In xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/*[name()='ArrayOfCommodityData']/*[name()='CommodityData']")
        r = r + 1
        With ActiveSheet
            .Cells(r, 1) = node.ChildNodes(0).Text
            .Cells(r, 2) = node.ChildNodes(6).Text
            .Cells(r, 3) = node.ChildNodes(11).Text
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, your iteration it's very useful in my idea and project, using alongside the solution proposed by @barrowc, returned the response I wanted, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've reached this solution, mixing the two answers, and sharing the code to help others.

First I set the property and then used the iteration to retrieve the values I needed, I don't know if this is the best solution, since I can't control the XML structure and if they change their file I'll need to return to this code.

I tried to work in a "Safety Line" to avoid any mistake in the output, but no problem for me to double check since I have access to the data itself.

```
If node.childNodes(0).text = "Production" And node.childNodes(6).text = "Argentina" Then
```

To ensure that the name and response will bring whatever I want.

```
Public Sub test_3()
    Dim xmlDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Dim URL As String, APIkey As String

    APIkey = "8DB688F8-1E22-4031-B581-59C221ECDDA6"

    URL = "https://apps.fas.usda.gov/PSDOnlineDataServices/api/CommodityData/GetCommodityDataByYear?commodityCode=2222000&marketYear=2018"

    Set xmlDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", URL, False
        .SetRequestHeader "Accept", "text/xml"
        .SetRequestHeader "API_KEY", APIkey
        .Send
        xmlDoc.loadXML .ResponseText
        xmlDoc.SetProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:r='http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/PSDOnline.DataServices.Models'"
    End With

    Dim node As IXMLDOMElement, r As Long

    For Each node In xmlDoc.selectNodes("//r:CommodityData")
        If node.childNodes(0).text = "Production" And node.childNodes(6).text = "Argentina" Then
        r = r + 1
        Debug.Print node.childNodes(0).text
        Debug.Print node.childNodes(6).text
        Debug.Print node.LastChild.text
        'With ActiveSheet
            '.Cells(r, 1) = node.childNodes(0).text
            '.Cells(r, 2) = node.childNodes(6).text
            '.Cells(r, 3) = node.LastChild.text
        'End With
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

This solution return the following response in the DEBUGGER:

**Production**

**Argentina**

**55300.0000**

Exactly what I wanted.

Thanks again for the time and for sharing knowledge.